# Correct Usage and omission of "the"

Tags: definite-article

I have a question regarding the usage of **the**. Should I use **the** in the following sentence?

Suppose I am a sports teacher in my school. I enter a class in my school and want to know if the students in the class would like to play soccer today. So, should I use **the** in the following sentence?

Here's the context:

- Hi everyone, Today we will play soccer. (The)students who want to play join me at the school ground.

I know it is better to use **those** or **"anyone who wants to...** instead of **(The)students**. But I want to know whether I should use **the** or not. I am sorry because I think I am unable to provide a better context than this. I Hope you get what I want to know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coach is addressing **a large group of students some of whom may play soccer**: s/he might say "the" here. The the would mean only those ones.

Otherwise, as a general statement (on a bulletin board, for example), it would not take the.

[it's football pitch [UK, etc. and soccer field [US]

Comment: Thank you. here is another example, should I use the ?

This notice is for (the) students who did not receive admit cards for the examinations. As you know the college issued admit card to students appearing in next week's exams. (The) Students who did not come to take admit cards yesterday are requested to take them by tomorrow.

Comment: The same idea applies. Neither is grammatically incorrect. Presumably, some students are in the not-receiving group.